# Angular Material Sort (matSort) causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I dont normally working with JS or angular or event node, but needed to get a UI going for an application I'm building. I'm just learning on the go and have been able to figure out most problems. Currently I'm getting this ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error in angular, there are a few places where a similar question was asked but I did not understand very well, so I'm asking here again.
This is my component.ts

```
export class xComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
  // Columns that will appear in the list view
  columnsToDisplay = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b'];
  // Keep the list view columns and expand the css selection area to display additional information
  columnsToDisplayWithExpand = [...this.columnsToDisplay, 'expand'];

  expandedElement: tab | null;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<tab>;
  
  data: tab[] = [];

  // Paginator component to use
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  // Sort component to use
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  // To indicate results are being loaded, a spinner or such
  isLoadingResults = true;
  resultsLength: number = 0;
  // Service that will get data from Device
  dataFromService$: Observable<tab[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<tab>(this.data);
    this.dataFromService$ = of(tab_data);
    this.dataFromService$.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    })


  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {
    console.log('sort')
  }
}
```

After many iterations, and looking at examples and solutions and getting the page to completely stop working, i've finally got to this point above, where pagination and sorting both work, but I keep getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`
It seems to suggest that I've changed data after view was initialized, but I dont see what data,
If I move the sort binding to ngAfterContentInit() or in the constructor itself, the error goes away but sort stops working.

Can anyone let me know what's going on here..
Thanks,
Also, dont know if this is relevant, but I've built upon the example of expandable rows from Angular Mat Table examples here [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Comment: This error happens when something that you're doing causes a change detection cycle to happen. It's not a huge problem and won't even be displayed to the user when your running in production mode.  If, however, you want to get it gone, then the solution is to have the thing that you're doing to not happen until the next change detection cycle.  You can use ng Zones for that, or what I do is I set a timeout with 0 delay: setTimeout(() => {this.dataSource.sort = this.sort});  This will cause the thing to happen on the next change detection cycle.

Comment: I recommend doing the sort thing in a setter of matSort: @ViewChild(MatSort)
  set matSort(sort: MatSort) {
    this.dataSource.sort = sort;
  }

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Thanks, this way works as well too, although had a weird side effect of starting with all table rows expanded!

Comment: Thanks @FunkMonkey33 got me reading about Angular Change detection and zone.js which is handy

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of that error by enclosing your code inside a setTimeout function with 0 delay, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}, 0);
```